# isalnum и кирилица

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь в своем проэкте считать кирилицу:

```
bool Helper::IsAllNum(char symbol)
{
    if (isalpha(symbol))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
std::string Helper::CheckItem(std::string & word)
{

    if (!word.empty())
    {
        while (IsAllNum(word.back()))
        {
            word.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Читал, советуют использовать unsigned, но это только помогает для пробелов и islower - toupper, пытался проверить вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        if (isalnum((unsigned char)i))
        {
            cout << i << "   " << char(i) << "\n";
        }
    }
```

без результатно, что посоветуете сделать?

Идея в том, что мне нужно спарсить файл, я получаю слово в конце с запятыми и т.п., нужно проверить, что бы небыло ничего лишнего в конце строки и записать слово в map. С англ. работает идеально, с русским не как.

Comment: Файл необходимо разбирать с учетом его кодировки (которая в вопросе не указана). Код собственно чтения из фала тоже отсутствует. Стандартная функция `isalpha` проверяет только  A - Z и a - z

Comment: На лабораторной было подобное задание и действительно помогал вариант с SetConsoleCP
Как бы не говорили, что работать не должно, все равно стоит попробовать

Comment: isalpha() требует `unsigned char` аргумента, то есть работает только с однобайтовыми символами. А русские буквы в большинстве современных систем кодируются более чем одним байтом. Используйте `iswalpha()` или его эквивалент в вашей системе.

Answer (score 3):

**isalnum** проверяет, является ли символ буквой или цифрой в *текущей* локали.

Для того, чтобы выставить русскую локаль нужно воспользоваться функцией  **std::setlocale**

Comment: Это не особо поможет. Разве что строчка имеет однобайтовую кодировку, что было бы очень странно.

Comment: Мне не нужне вывод на экран, причем тут setlocale вообще..

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь мне нужно что бы с файла считалась русская строка и проверилась функцией isalnum(), если присутствуют символы то удалить их из строки и вернуть обработанную строку.

Comment: Только вот isalnum() не работает с кирилицей.

Comment: Ну, кириллица бывает в нескольких кодировках. Какую именно кодировку имеет "кирилица"?
По стандарту isalnum учитывает текущую установленную локаль.
Но, в некоторых компиляторах, в зависимости от ключей isalnum может оказаться просто макросом проверяющим попадание аргумента в соответствующие диапазоны ASCII таблицы. В этом случае кирилица выпадет.
Т. е. чтобы корректно ответить нужно понимать какая кодировка, какая система, какой компилятор и какие опции компиляции.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в `isalnum` нельзя передавать `char`, т.к. у русских символов будут отрицательные значения, а функция `isalnum` принимает только значения в диапазоне 0-255 или `EOF`.

Во-вторых, должна быть установлена нужная локаль. `isalnum` и прочие функции классифицируют символы через таблицы в локали, и локаль по-умолчанию умеет только английские буквы.

В-третьих кодировка файла должна быть однобайтовой, т.к. `isalnum` принимает только один символ, и не может работать с UTF-8.

Локаль устанавливается функцией `setlocale`.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.cp1251");
    char c = '\xfe';  // 'ю' in cp1251
    bool alnum = isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    std::cout << "isalnum=" << alnum << "\n";
}
```

При этом локаль должна быть установлена в системе, например на линуксе это выглядит так:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
$ ./a.out 
isalnum=0
```

-- не работает.

Устанавливаем локаль

```
$ sudo localedef --no-archive -c -i ru_RU -f CP1251 ru_RU.CP1251
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
ru_RU.cp1251
$ ./a.out 
isalnum=1
```

-- работает.

Comment: Да, для винды название локалей отличаются.

Answer (score -2):

Для того, чтобы изменить кодировку используйте либо заголовочный файл `windows.h` и следующие две строки кода в начале функции `main`

```
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConloleOutputCP(1251);
 // Остальной код
```

Либо заголовочный файл `clocale` и строку кода

```
  char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Также можно воспользоваться этой командой если у вас к примеру английская версия ОС

```
  char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
```

Для чтения данных из файла в `C++` используется класс `ifsteam`. Нужно создать объект этого класса и помощью него считать данные (побайтово или построчно). Для побайтового считывания:

```
 ifstream fin;
 fin.open ("Путь к файлу");
 // проверяем удалось ли открыть файл
 if (!fin.is_open){

 cout << "ошибка открытия файла";
 } 
 else {
 cout << "Файл успешно открыт";
 char ch;
 while (fin.get(ch)){
 // Далее в цикле нужно проверить является ли данный символ русской буквой.
 int char_code = (int)ch;
 // Будем проверять код каждой буквы согласно ANSI-таблице
 if (char_code >=127 && char_code <=255){
 // Далее нужно обработать файл с помощью объекта класса ofstream
 } 
 }
 }
```

Comment: `SetConsoleCP` совершенно бесполезен при чтении из файла. И уж конечно не стоит использовать однобайтовую кодировку в 2019 году. Ну и локаль соответственно не поможет.

Comment: SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConloleOutputCP(1251); // вообще не как не помогает, пробовал самым первым

Comment: char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN"); А куда потом это вставлять, или просто в мейн положить?

Comment: @АртемМазуров в main.

Comment: @АртемМазуров Отредактировал ответ. Надеюсь, что поможет.